# email alerts for Windows Services

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I set an e-mail alert for Starting & Stopping Windows Service?
I have Tomcat running in Windows Server 2008 R2 as Service, I want to setup e-mail alerts whenever the service starts/stopped/re-started.?

is there any Powershell commands? Any Windows event based triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of scheduling a recurring task as @cad suggests, you can create a task that will be triggered based on the eventlog :
[image]

you could configure it to start on event **7036** of source **Service Control Manager** from **System** logfile.

This task can run a powershell script where you can send mail. Short example

```
Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source "service control manager" -After (get-date).AddMinutes(-5) |?{$_.message -match "tomcat"} | select timegenerated, message
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many solutions possible (like using Nagios to monitor service status and send an alert).

If you want to use **PowerShell**...

**SOLUTION1**: Use Recovery tab to schedule an action ("Run a program"). That action should be a PowerShell script that sends your email...

NOTE: As Jacob kindly said in a comment, action will be triggered **only if the service stops by an error**.

[image]

**SOLUTION2**: Another possible solution is having a Schedule Task every x time (your choose... 1 min is the minimum) that runs a PowerShell Script. That scripts would:

1. Check Service Status and compare with previous state (use [Get-Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx) cmdlet)
2. If the state changes, change previous state and send an email.

You can find here someone that had exactly the [same problem](http://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/using-powershell-to-send-a-windows-service-recovery-email-alert/) and fixed it with Powershell.

Comment: Just a quick comment on using the Recovery feature of a service. AFAIK this only takes action on an application/service crash. If someone logs on the server and stop the service gracefully, the program would not run.  Also it will not catch any other state changes (start/restarted)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into creating a WMI eventing (Win32_Service Class). I haven't used this feature in quite a long time but it look like powershell is making it easier now. This would provide immediate alerting and not require a separate polling process.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/an-insiders-guide-to-using-wmi-events-and-powershell/